# Bash script is not running in my crontab (AWS ec2 linux)

Tags: node.js, bash, cron

Following has been set to crontab:

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
* * * * * /var/www/NODE_PROJECT/cron-bash.sh
```

cron-bash.sh has following code :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Job initiated !!!"
node app.js
```

I can see error log as

```
CROND[17889]: (root) CMD (/var/www/NODE_PROJECT/cron-bash.sh)
```

Comment: Is the `app.js`  is with in your `PATH` ?

Answer (score 0):

First you should be sure your script is executable

```
chmod +rx /var/www/NODE_PROJECT/cron-bash.sh
```

then add source to you bash profile and absolute paths

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bash_profile #or .bashrc
echo "Job initiated !!!"
/path/to/node /path/to/app.js
```

or last line can be

```
cd /path/to #app.js file
/path/to/node app.js
```

And consider if you really need to run this app every minute