# program not work with crontab (path problem)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path, cron

I use the program astrometry.net whose file path is in "/home/desktop/astrometry.net" and I call this program in python.

runs smoothly when I run the program manually but when it runs with crontab, the program can't find the astrometry.net path and doesn't work.

i do that in terminal:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/home/desktop/astrometry.net/bin"
```

but didn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions? (Ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [crontab PATH and USER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129381/crontab-path-and-user)

Comment: crontab doesn't use your PATH. See linked post or search for "crontab path" for more posts.

Comment: Or read this. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info . Good luck.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60565021/2908599